# Custom derived Component not accessible in Components collection on Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm building a custom ToolTip in Winforms. I also have a theming system that iterates through controls and components. Problem being, whilst my methods pick up normal tooltips, they don't seem to pick up my custom tooltip inherited from winforms' base tooltip component. Here's the abridged relevant code:

```cs
public class ToolTipExt : System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip
{
    //Stuff
}

private void GetAllComponents(Object obj)
{
    IEnumerable<Component> components = GetComponents(obj);
}

public IEnumerable<Component> GetComponents(Object obj)
{
    FieldInfo fi = obj.GetType().GetField("components", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    if (fi?.GetValue(obj) is IContainer container)
    {
        return container.Components.OfType<Component>();
    }
    else
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Component>();
    }
}
```

The `Form` is passd into `GetAllComponents`. So, if I drop a standard `Windows.Forms.ToolTip` onto the form, it will be picked up in `components`. However, if I drop a `ToolTipExt` onto the form, it's not picked up in `components`. The full class is pretty long, but can post if needed. However, the main body is just custom properties to assist with custom drawing of the tooltip with overridden `OnPopup` and `OnDraw` Events.

There's obviously something I'm missing, but from basic principles, I can't understand it given it inherits directly from ToolTip. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to show the Constructors (plural) of your custom Component. Or just say whether you forgot to add this one: `public ToolTipExt(IContainer container) : this() {container.Add(this); }`

Comment: That did it thanks. Yeah - my knowledge of creating component objects is very sketchy, I just assumed it would inherit everything it needed. I also had to mess about with Implements for both IComponent and IContainer and ended up with a few null methods and properties for good measure, eventually removing the implementing, but things seem to work. Janky, but operative! 

Comment: The ending notes here: [Custom component works in the Designer, but is invisible in code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67032980/7444103) may be useful

Comment: Thank, Jimi. You're a true Winforms ninja. So my reading of this is by including the second constructor, it will prompt the designer file to include code which will ensure correct disposal of the component object? Just to double check - I don't have to include a Dispose method in my custom class? (I did re-implement IContainer, but it doesn't seem to require Dispose as a member, so I'm guessing that's ok?). On another note, I'm still curios as towards why this doesn't get inherited..

Comment: You just need to ensure that your Component can be added to the components Container. The Constructor that accepts an `IContainer` argument is enough. This also instructs the Serializer to create the IContainer object (the `components` Field) if it doesn't exist -- You need to override the default `Dispose(bool disposing)` method if you need to dispose unmanaged resources you create or you need, e.g., to remove event handlers in a specific order (to avoid unwanted cascading effects) or other references that need *special care*, etc. Otherwise it's not needed

Comment: Note that a Component can host other Components; in this case, it needs its own IContainer. The standard Component Template includes these by default. You can create a Component using the Template VS provides, then replace `: Component` with `: ToolTip`

Comment: Cheers fella - helpful as ever. 